# Expecting: '/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64' but was: '/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre'

Tags: android, java-7, java

I have a jdk setting error when using android studio. The problem shows:

```
 Expecting: '/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64' but was: '/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre'
```

But I have already changed JAVA_HOME in .bashrc file and added it into path, here is the JAVA_HOME and PATH output.

```
echo $JAVA_HOME

/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64

echo $PATH
 /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin:/home/zhucan/hadoop-2.7.1/sbin:/home/zhucan/hadoop-2.7.1/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin:/home/zhucan/hadoop-2.7.1/sbin:/home/zhucan/hadoop-2.7.1/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin

which java
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java
```

Why output of which java is not /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin/java? Bacause I add the JAVA_HOME into path. How should I fix the problem to make android studio work? Any suggestions. Thanks very much.

Comment: check your build.gradle of your project. There is problem with your libraries. Try eliminating useless libraries.

Comment: buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.1'
}
dependencies {
} Here is the build.gradle, but I have no libraries in it.

Comment: Are you using V4, V7 or any other library with version other than 23.0.1. Because the version code should match with the buildtoolsversion 23.0.1

Comment: I use V7, so the buildtoolsversion should be changed?

Comment: use this version of v7  "
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'"

Comment: No, it still didn't work. This is a jdk problem, maybe it has no relationship with buildtools.

Comment: I faced this problem everytime I import existing project into android studio and resolved issue like this only.. May be in your case it's different..